# Icon of running firefox in the specific profile in gnome

Tags: gnome, firefox, icons, gnome-session-fallback

I have few firefox profiles, which are launched as different processes in the panel header. Like that:

[image]

How can I customize icon of the firefox in the process menu? I mean this icon:

[image]

Comment: you mean just on the panel or you want to changre the firefox icon at all ?

Comment: Just on bottom panel. That's enough

Comment: I dont think this is possible

Comment: I can change firefox icon at all profile, if it's possble

Comment: I answered you check the answer

Answer (score 1):

**For the panel, you need this:**

```
mkdir ~/.icons
mkdir ~/.icons/<your_icon_theme>
mkdir ~/.icons/<your_icon_theme>/32x32
mkdir ~/.icons/<your_icon_theme>/22x22
mkdir ~/.icons/<your_icon_theme>/16x16
mkdir ~/.icons/<your_icon_theme>/22x22/status
mkdir ~/.icons/<your_icon_theme>/16x16/status
```

Place your icon in

- `~/.icons/<your_icon_theme>/32x32/status`
- `~/.icons/<your_icon_theme>/22x22/status`
- `~/.icons/<your_icon_theme>/16x16/status`

The name of the image file must match the name that the image had in

- `/usr/share/icons/<your_icon_theme>/32x32/status`
- `/usr/share/icons/<your_icon_theme>/22x22/status`
- `/usr/share/icons/<your_icon_theme>/16x16/status`.

Then restart your GNOME session.

---

**For the launcher, you need this:**

Create your custom desktop file for Firefox. The files in `~/.local/share/applications/` take precedence over the system directory `/usr/share/applications/` if they have the same name.

```
cp /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

Open the file with:

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

Find the line that begins with `Icon=` and replace the value `firefox` with your prefered icon path, eg:

```
Icon=<my_firefox_icon_path>
```

If you want to use another image from your icon theme, then use the name of the file without extension, eg:

```
Icon=mozilla-firefox
```

The images of your icon theme are in this directory

```
/usr/share/icons/<your_icon_theme>
```

Comment: Why you just copy paste my answer?! What is the added value in yours? PLus your answer will work just for this user not for others?!

Comment: @NewUSer That's a completely different approach.

Comment: I dont think so. It's the same...

Comment: @NewUSer this solution makes a local copy of the .desktop file and avoids editing system files. It is not the same as yours which suggests editing files in `/usr`.

Comment: I've tried this. I still see icon at the bottom as original firefox...

Comment: Bottom of what? =)

Comment: Ah, I understand, in the panel

Comment: Oh, I've tried this, but with no success. Bottom panel is still show me the original firefox icon when I run firefox from customized `.desktop` file

Comment: P.S. I use gnome-session-flashback

Comment: These icons depend on the icon theme. Which is your icon theme?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23539/discussion-between-asiniy-and-a-b).

Comment: @A.B. thanks for answer, but how can I set original icon for one profile, and set new icon for another in the bottom panel?

Comment: That's a good question. I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit the ‘firefox.desktop’**

The ‘.desktop’ files are usually stored in “/usr/share/applications/”.

```
cd /usr/share/applications

sudo gedit firefox.desktop
```

**Change the value of Icon**

```
Icon=/path-to-your-icon
```

Now save and exit.

Open Firefox again from Dash then Enjoy :)

Comment: Why the downvote?!

Comment: Oh, I've tried this, but with no success. Bottom panel is still show me the original firefox icon when I run firefox from customized `.desktop` file